# Powershell Group objects in an array by value to new variable

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a query to sql.

```
$query1 = "SELECT id,in_fname,in_lname,att_app_name, FROM events    
$dataAdapter1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$dataAdapter1.SelectCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($query1,$connString)
$commandBuilder = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder $dataAdapter1
$dt1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dataAdapter1.fill($dt1)
$reg = $dt1
```

What I need to do is group the results by "id" and then pass along a foreach "do something" to each group.

Something like

```
foreach ($group in $reg) { do something }
```

can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Group-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176864.aspx) cmdlet.

```
$groups = $reg | group-object -property id;
foreach ($group in $groups) {
# Do stuff
}
```